# How to solve NSErrorFailingURLStringKey in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsurlrequest

I am new to iOS. I am developing an application which retrieves data from a server using the HTTP POST method.
I pass an NSDictionary as POST parameters with my URL.

NSDictionary format is like this:

```
{
"draw_id" = 6;
"block_numers" =     {
    "block_number" = 1;
    "draw_day" = Both;
    "number_1" = 1;
    "number_2" = 3;
    "number_3" = 20;
    "number_4" = 25;
    "number_5" = 40;
    "star_1" = 2;
    "star_2" = 6;
};
"game_id" = 1;
"user_id" = 51;
}
```

And my url is `http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:3000/xxxxxxx_protocol_xxx`

I used following function to retrieve data from server.

```
-(NSDictionary*)getJsonDataFromPostURl:(NSString *)postUrl JsonParserType:(NSString *)type PostData:(NSDictionary *)postData{

NSData *jsonData = [self jsonTrackDataForUploadingToCloud:postData];  // Method shown below.
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//NSLog(@"Json String: %@ URL: %@", jsonString,postUrl);  // To verify the jsonString.

NSLog(@"GetJsonDataFromPostUrl: JsonString: %@",jsonString);

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:postUrl];

NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60];
[postRequest setHTTPMethod:type];
[postRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[postRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[postRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[postRequest setHTTPBody:jsonData];

NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *requestError = nil;
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:postRequest returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];

if (requestError == nil) {
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[returnData bytes] length:[returnData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[returnString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];
    if([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
        return result;
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest error: %@", requestError);
}
return nil;
}
```

this function is working correctly with other Parameters and other api but is return following error with this API:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo=0x7a228e10 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=payment_protocol_api, NSErrorFailingURLKey=payment_protocol_api, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x7a701f50 "unsupported URL"}
```

Please help me out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: That error would happen if `postUrl` contains nothing more than `payment_protocol_api`. Which would be the last path argument in your expected URL `http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:3000/xxxxxxx_protocol_xxx`. I would look for the problem where you create the string that you pass to this `getJsonDataFromPostURl:JsonParserType:PostData:` method. Use the debugger to step through your code.

Comment: `if (requestError == nil)` is incorrect, an error is indicated by `returnData` being nil. `requestError` is not guaranteed to be nil for all error free requests.

Comment: As @MatthiasBauch says, debug your code by inspecting with the debugger and using `NSLog()` as necessary, Also use Charles Proxy to examine what is actually sent and received.

Comment: Thank you guys. I found the problem there some mistake in URL passing i solved that and it working thank you so much.

Comment: What mistake was there in URL passing ? Would you share it. I am facing same issue..

Comment: The URL is somehow invalid and so cant be used to fetch data. What happens if you put in the URL in your browser?